# Can't get data from JSON Object (Android)

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I can't parse a JSON response from an url ("http://www.telekino.com.ar/cupones/control/1267/1027027/84.json")

```
{"kino":{"ganador":false,"diferencia":""},"rekino":{"ganador":false,"diferencia":""},"carton_formateado":"1.027.027","cupon_numeros":"","premio_extra":false,"cupon_caducidad":"22\/08\/2016","cupon_erroneo":true}
```

I used a `JSONViewer` to understand the tree, and is very simple, but I can't get the booleans, strings, etc. I always receive null results

```
JsonURL= "http://www.telekino.com.ar/cupones/control/1267/1027027/84.json"

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, JsonURL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object= response.getJSONObject("object");
                        algoerroneo = object.getBoolean("algo_erroneo");
                        JSONObject kino = object.getJSONObject("kino");
                        kinoganador = kino.getBoolean("ganador");
                        JSONObject data = kino.getJSONObject("data");
                        JSONObject Categoria = data.getJSONObject("Categoria");
                        Smonto = Categoria.getString("monto");
                        JSONObject Ganador = data.getJSONObject("Ganador");
                        Saciertos = Ganador.getString("aciertos");
                        JSONObject rekino = object.getJSONObject("rekino");
                        rekinoganador = rekino.getBoolean("ganador");
                        objetoslist = object.toString();

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                data=String.valueOf(algoerroneo)+" "+String.valueOf(kinoganador)+" "+String.valueOf(rekinoganador)+ "\n"+objetoslist;
                results.setText(data);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                text8.setText("shit2");
            }
        });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.

MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: response.getJSONObject("object");  there is no param name with "object" directly start form "kino"

Comment: also param name "algo_erroneo" is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first line where you're getting the object 
`JSONObject object= response.getJSONObject("object")`;

This tries to find the `JSONObject` by the name of "object", however, you don't have any in your JSON. So, use `JSONObject` "response" parameter for referencing to the `objects`, `strings` or `boolean`.

For example like this:

```
JSONObject kino = response.getJSONObject("kino");
```

Comment: This works for me. Try this out:
JSONObject kino = response.getJSONObject("kino");
boolean ganador = kino.getBoolean("ganador");
String carton_formateado = response.getString("carton_formateado");

Comment: Its work for the string. Is not working for the boolean value "algo_erroneo" inside the root

Comment: Now is done!!!!, Was my mistake on the code with the name of the boolean!

Answer (score 2):

You can create class from JSON (using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/):

Result:

```
    -----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("kino")
@Expose
private Kino kino;
@SerializedName("rekino")
@Expose
private Rekino rekino;
@SerializedName("carton_formateado")
@Expose
private String cartonFormateado;
@SerializedName("cupon_numeros")
@Expose
private String cuponNumeros;
@SerializedName("premio_extra")
@Expose
private Boolean premioExtra;
@SerializedName("cupon_caducidad")
@Expose
private String cuponCaducidad;
@SerializedName("cupon_erroneo")
@Expose
private Boolean cuponErroneo;

public Kino getKino() {
return kino;
}

public void setKino(Kino kino) {
this.kino = kino;
}

public Rekino getRekino() {
return rekino;
}

public void setRekino(Rekino rekino) {
this.rekino = rekino;
}

public String getCartonFormateado() {
return cartonFormateado;
}

public void setCartonFormateado(String cartonFormateado) {
this.cartonFormateado = cartonFormateado;
}

public String getCuponNumeros() {
return cuponNumeros;
}

public void setCuponNumeros(String cuponNumeros) {
this.cuponNumeros = cuponNumeros;
}

public Boolean getPremioExtra() {
return premioExtra;
}

public void setPremioExtra(Boolean premioExtra) {
this.premioExtra = premioExtra;
}

public String getCuponCaducidad() {
return cuponCaducidad;
}

public void setCuponCaducidad(String cuponCaducidad) {
this.cuponCaducidad = cuponCaducidad;
}

public Boolean getCuponErroneo() {
return cuponErroneo;
}

public void setCuponErroneo(Boolean cuponErroneo) {
this.cuponErroneo = cuponErroneo;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Kino.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Kino {

@SerializedName("ganador")
@Expose
private Boolean ganador;
@SerializedName("diferencia")
@Expose
private String diferencia;

public Boolean getGanador() {
return ganador;
}

public void setGanador(Boolean ganador) {
this.ganador = ganador;
}

public String getDiferencia() {
return diferencia;
}

public void setDiferencia(String diferencia) {
this.diferencia = diferencia;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Rekino.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Rekino {

@SerializedName("ganador")
@Expose
private Boolean ganador;
@SerializedName("diferencia")
@Expose
private String diferencia;

public Boolean getGanador() {
return ganador;
}

public void setGanador(Boolean ganador) {
this.ganador = ganador;
}

public String getDiferencia() {
return diferencia;
}

public void setDiferencia(String diferencia) {
this.diferencia = diferencia;
}

}
```

Then

JsonURL= "http://www.telekino.com.ar/cupones/control/1267/1027027/84.json"

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, JsonURL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {





                    try {
                       // JSONObject object= response.getJSONObject("object");


                        JSONObject kinoObject = response.getJSONObject("kino");
                        JSONObject rekinoObject = response.getJSONObject("rekino");


                        Gson gson = new Gson();

                        Kino  kino = gson.fromJson(kinoObject.toString(), Kino.class);
                        Rekino  rekino = gson.fromJson(rekinoObject.toString(), Rekino.class);
                        Example example = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Example.class);



                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();

                    }








                    data=String.valueOf(algoerroneo)+" "+String.valueOf(kinoganador)+" "+String.valueOf(rekinoganador)+ "\n"+objetoslist;
                    results.setText(data);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    text8.setText("shit2");
                }
            });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

I hope it will help your problem!

Otherwise, you can use Retrofit, it is easily to use with JSON and HTTP!

Comment: I just modified a bit in the section, you can check it again.Nice to help you

Comment: Oh, sorry, i have a error, i edited it, you can check again!

Comment: Not yet, when i tried to get the Strings values, for example: (kinoganador= kino.getGanador();) I get a null value

Comment: for example, i need the boolean value algoerroneo, using your code I add this ..algoerroneo=example.getAlgoErroneo(); but the result is false (or null ) and must be true

Answer (score 1):

To avoid key and object related mistakes, you can use POJO and gson
First, create your POJO of your response from this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

then  cast your response with this object using gson library

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourPojoClass yourPojoClassObject = gson.fromJson(webresponse, YourPojoClass.class);
```

Now you can get values easily from yourPojoClassObject

Comment: what is webresponse?

Comment: public void onResponse(JSONObject response)  here response.toString() called web response.

Comment: My anwer is same as Thientvse different is he had explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

Download the RoboPOJOGenerator plugin and install it.It will convert the JSON String to java POJO class automatically.

https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator

And use the GSON library to store and retrieve the value in POJO class using below code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Classname objectname = gson.fromJson(jsonString,Classname.class);
```